# How to build a multiple Client and Server connection using sockets in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, websocket, tcpclient, tcplistener, tcpserver

I am trying to build a WebSocket connection using TCP protocol on my local Machine via nodejs. The connection is established between the server, web, and devices.

I am sending data from my asp.net web client using the serial number to node.js server and on the same server, the data is sent from another device using the same serial number as web.

By comparing serial numbers of devices and web, data is communicated from web to device and from device to web as clients using Node.js server.

When the web page communicates with the same serial number device it is working correctly with the first device but when a second web page is connected with the second device the data from the second device is received on the first web page. It is working correctly on window based applications and getting issues on Web-based applications.

```
var net = require('net');
var fs = require("fs");
var client = new net.Socket();
url = require('url');
var port = 8080;
const path = require('path');
var queueArray_W=[];
var queueArray_D=[];
var server = net.createServer();
server.listen(port, function(req, res){
   console.log('Server is listening at port' + port  + host);
   var address = server.address(); 
   var family = address.family;
   address.host = host; 
});

let sockets = [];
  server.on('connection', function(sock) {
  var ClientIP; 
ClientIP = sock.remoteAddress.replace('::ffff:',''); 
sockets.push(sock);
 sock.on('data', function(data) {
var str = data.toString('utf8');
   var client_data = str.split(':');
    sender = client_data[0];
   if(sender=="W")
    {queueArray_W.push(["W", client_data[1], client_data[2],ClientIP,sock.remotePort]);
      send_data_to_device("W", client_data[1], client_data[2])
    }
    else if (sender == "D")
   {queueArray_D.push(["D", client_data[1], client_data[2],ClientIP,sock.remotePort]);  
      send_data_to_web("D",client_data[1], client_data[2] ,ClientIP,sock.remotePort)
    }
function send_data_to_web(senderType, serialno, response ,  frmIp, frmport)
   {if(senderType == 'D')
      {for (var i = 0; i < queueArray_W.length; i++)
         {  if(queueArray_W[i][1] === serialno)
           { for (var j = 0; j < sockets.length; j++)     
               { if ((sockets[j].remoteAddress.replace('::ffff:', '') === queueArray_W[i][3]) && (sockets[j].remotePort === queueArray_W[i][4]))
                        { sockets[j].write(response+":"+serialno);
                           console.log("write" +response +"sno: " +serialno)
                           break                     
                         } }}}
```

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: Not in the comments try to put that in the question.

Comment: The data from device received on server is like D:serialnumber:0:0 and same as from web like W:serialnumber:0:0  and if serial number of device matches with web serial number then data should be send from device to web and viseversa.